# Tabularx and Longtable Alignment

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, longtable, tabularx, alignment

I'm trying to write my CV using `tabularx`, but I'm having some problems with getting some things to align. I'm using `tabularx` for sections on single pages, but `longtable` for sections spanning multiple pages. But the resulting tables do not align. Here's a section of a (fake) CV illustrating the issue:

[image]

As you can just about see, the faint grey line has again been shifted rightwards in the longtable compared to the regular tables. How can I rectify this without changing all the tables to longtables? Thanks!

Here's the code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=20mm]{geometry}
\title{\vspace{-15mm}\huge JOE BLOGGS\vspace{-5mm}}
\author{joebloggs@gmail.com}
\date{}

\usepackage{baskervillef} %font
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %font
\usepackage{nopageno} %eliminates page numbers
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec} %adjust titles
\usepackage{longtable} %multi-page tables

\usepackage{array, xcolor}
\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.8}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedleft}p{0.14\textwidth}}
\newcolumntype{R}{p{0.8\textwidth}}
\newcommand\VRule{\color{lightgray}\vrule width 0.5pt}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\titleformat{\section}{\normalfont}{\thesection}{1em}{\MakeUppercase{#1}}[\vspace{1mm} \titlerule]

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\noindent Areas of Particular Interest: dogs, aardvarks, amazing birds of paradise.

\vspace{1mm}

\noindent Areas of Interest: cats, honey badgers, goldfish.

\section*{Education}
\begin{tabular}{L!{\VRule}R}
    2018—2020 & MPhil in Zoology, University A.\\
    & \hspace{5mm} MPhil Thesis: \textit{999 Reasons Why Dogs Are Better than Cats}\\
    & \hspace{5mm} Supervisors: Scooby \& Snoopy\\
    & \hspace{5mm} Examiners: Fido (Internal) \& Laika (External) \vspace{1mm}\\
    2014—2017 & BA in Zoology (First), University B.\\
\end{tabular}

\section*{Works in Progress}
\begin{tabular}{L!{\VRule}R}
    2020 & \textit{Aardvarks and Their Discontents.} Revise \& resubmit in the \textit{Journal of Zoology}. \vspace{1mm}\\
    2020 & \textit{Should We Care for Wild Animals?} Revise \& resubmit in \textit{Zoological Studies}.
\end{tabular}

\section*{Presentations}

\begin{tabular}{L!{\VRule}R}
    February 2021 & \textit{Should Animals Be Sent into Space?} Paper to be presented at the 24\textsuperscript{th} Oxford Zoology Graduate Conference, University of Oxford, UK.\vspace{1mm}\\
    July 2020 & \textit{Why Do Cats Hate Water?} Paper presented at the 13\textsuperscript{th} Annual Cambridge Graduate Conference on Zoology, University of Cambridge, UK.\vspace{1mm}\\
\end{tabular}

\vspace{\baselineskip}

\begin{tabular}{L!{\VRule}R}
    February 2020 & \textit{Are Cats Really Smarter than Dogs? A Summary of Recent Research}. Paper presented at the Friday Seminar, University A, UK.\vspace{1mm}\\
    December 2019 & \textit{How Many Times Did Laika Orbit the Earth? Ethical Issues Surrounding Space Exploration} Paper presented at the Zoology Group, University A, UK.\vspace{1mm}\\
\end{tabular}

\section*{Awards}

\begin{tabular}{L!{\VRule}R}
    2020 & Generic academic award for being amazing, contributing to the department, and many other things. University A, UK.\vspace{1mm}\\
    2020 & Another generic academic award for being amazing, contributing to the department, and many other things. University A, UK.\vspace{1mm}\\
    2020 & Another generic award for being amazing, contributing to the department, and many other things. University A, UK.\vspace{1mm}\\
    2020 & Another generic award for being amazing, contributing to the department, and many other things. University A, UK.\vspace{1mm}\\
    2020 & Another generic award for being amazing, contributing to the department, and many other things. University A, UK.\vspace{1mm}\\
\end{tabular}

\section*{Teaching Experience}

\begin{longtable}{L!{\VRule}R}
    2020 & Taught Undergraduates Zoology. University A, UK.\\
    2020 & Taught Undergraduates Zoology. University A, UK.\\
    2020 & Taught Undergraduates Zoology. University A, UK.\\
    2020 & Taught Undergraduates Zoology. University A, UK.\\
    2020 & Taught Undergraduates Zoology. University A, UK.\\
\end{longtable}

\section*{Academic Service}

\begin{tabular}{L!{\VRule}R}
    2020 & Head of the Zoology Society. University A, UK.\vspace{1mm}\\
    2020 & Convenor of the Zoology Reading Group. University A, UK.\vspace{1mm}\\
    2020 & Referee, Zoology Graduate Conference. University A, UK.\vspace{1mm}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Add in the preamble `\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}` to delete indentation.

Comment: Thanks! That gets rid of the first right shift but doesn't solve the problem with `longtable` which is still slightly shifted to the right. Any ideas on what's causing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is that what you want ?

If you want to change `\title` , open `article.cls`, copy paste and change `\maketitle` as you want :

```latex
\makeatletter
    \def\@maketitle{%
  \newpage
  \null
  \vskip 2em%
  \begin{center}%
  \let \footnote \thanks
    {\huge \@title \par}% <=\LARGE by default
    \vskip 1.5em%
    {\large
      \lineskip .5em%
      \begin{tabular}[t]{c}%
        \@author
      \end{tabular}\par}%
    \vskip 1em%
    {\large \@date}%
  \end{center}%
  \par
  \vskip 1.5em}
\makeatother
```

Edit :

```latex
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{tabularx}{\medskip}%before
\AtEndEnvironment{tabularx}{\medskip}%after
\usepackage[margin=20mm]{geometry}
\title{ JOE BLOGGS}
\author{joebloggs@gmail.com}
\date{}

\usepackage{baskervillef} %font
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %font
\usepackage{nopageno} %eliminates page numbers
\usepackage[nobottomtitles,explicit]{titlesec} %adjust titles
\usepackage{array,tabularx,longtable} %multi-page tables
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.8}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedleft}p{0.14\textwidth}}
\newcolumntype{R}{p{0.8\textwidth}}
\newcommand\VRule{\color{lightgray}\vrule width 0.5pt}%no need | do the same job perfectly

%\titleformat{\section}{\normalfont}{\textbf{}}{0em}{\textbf{#1}}

\titleformat{\section}{\normalfont}{\thesection}{1em}{\MakeUppercase{#1}}[ \titlerule]

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{5pt}
\arrayrulecolor{gray}
\usepackage{lipsum}


    
    
\begin{document}

\maketitle

 Areas of Particular Interest: dogs, aardvarks, amazing birds of paradise.



 Areas of Interest: cats, honey badgers, goldfish.

\section*{Education}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{L|@{\quad}R}
    2018--2020 & MPhil in Zoology, University A.\\
%   & Attained distinctions in every module in first year.\\
    &  MPhil Thesis: \textit{999 Reasons Why Dogs Are Better than Cats}\\
    & Supervisors: Scooby \& Snoopy\\
    & Examiners: Fido (Internal) \& Laika (External) \\
    2014--2017 & BA in Zoology (First), University B.\\
    %& \hspace{5mm} Upper Second Class.\\
    %2011--2013 & \textbf{A Levels, King Edward VI School (Southampton)}\\
    %& Mathematics (A*), Chemistry (A*), Biology (A*), \& Economics (A*).
\end{tabularx}

\section*{Works in Progress}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{L|@{\quad}R}
    2020 & \textit{Aardvarks and Their Discontents.} Revise \& resubmit in the \textit{Journal of Zoology}. \\
    2020 & \textit{Should We Care for Wild Animals?} Revise \& resubmit in \textit{Zoological Studies}.
\end{tabularx}

\section*{Presentations}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{L|@{\quad}R}
    February 2021 & \textit{Should Animals Be Sent into Space?} Paper to be presented at the 24\textsuperscript{th} Oxford Zoology Graduate Conference, University of Oxford, UK.\\
    July 2020 & \textit{Why Do Cats Hate Water?} Paper presented at the 13\textsuperscript{th} Annual Cambridge Graduate Conference on Zoology, University of Cambridge, UK.\\
\end{tabularx}

%\vspace{\baselineskip} %no need etooolbox do this for you

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{L|@{\quad}R}
    February 2020 & \textit{Are Cats Really Smarter than Dogs? A Summary of Recent Research}. Paper presented at the Friday Seminar, University A, UK.\\
    December 2019 & \textit{How Many Times Did Laika Orbit the Earth? Ethical Issues Surrounding Space Exploration} Paper presented at the Zoology Group, University A, UK.\\
\end{tabularx}

\section*{Awards}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{L|@{\quad}R}
    2020 & Generic academic award for being amazing, contributing to the department, and many other things. University A, UK.\\
    2020 & Another generic academic award for being amazing, contributing to the department, and many other things. University A, UK.\\
    2020 & Another generic award for being amazing, contributing to the department, and many other things. University A, UK.\\
    2020 & Another generic award for being amazing, contributing to the department, and many other things. University A, UK.\\
    2020 & Another generic award for being amazing, contributing to the department, and many other things. University A, UK.\\
\end{tabularx} 

\section*{Teaching Experience}

\begin{longtable}{L|@{\quad}R}
   2020 & \lipsum[1]\\
    2020 & \lipsum[1]\\
    2020 & Taught Undergraduates Zoology. University A, UK.\\
    2020 & Taught Undergraduates Zoology. University A, UK.\\
    2020 & Taught Undergraduates Zoology. University A, UK.\\
\end{longtable}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Not quite: I want to use `longtable` for sections which span over multiple pages, but when I do so the faint grey line is shifted rightwards slightly. In the original example this section was entitled 'Teaching Experience', but in your answer its been changed to `tabularx`.

Comment: I edit my answer. You can use `supertabular`package. You get the same result.

Comment: You can add `nobottomtitles`option to `titlesec` to get section title in the top of the next page.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Is there a way of resolving this issue that doesn't involve changing all the tables to longtables? I've edited the question to make it clearer what I'm after so that it just focusses on the `tabularx` and `longtable` alignment issue.

Comment: Do you mean you want just `tabularx ` for some tabular environments and just `longtable ` when you want page break ?

Comment: Yes, exactly – I only want to use `longtable` for sections which span over two pages. In essence, all I want is for the faint grey line in the `tabularx` environment to align with the faint grey line in the `longtable` environment

Comment: I edit my answer, change `longtable` to `tabularx`. I put  blindtext in `longtable ` to show page break.

Comment: `tabularx` can't break the page. If you want  use `xltabular`instead. `\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{L|@{\quad}X}` instead of R. see [documentation](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xltabular).

Comment: Thanks. I know `tabularx` can't break the page, which is why I used `longtable` for the section entitled 'Teaching Experience'. But the faint grey lines in the `tabularx` tables still don't align with the longtables...

Comment: sorry, I haven't logged in for more than a week . For me all vertical lines (what you call faint grey lines ?) are aligned. See my result.